# pandas.Series() Creation using DataFrame Columns returns NaN Data entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Im attempting to convert a dataframe into a series using code which, simplified, looks like this:

```
dates = ['2016-1-{}'.format(i)for i in range(1,21)]
values = [i for i in range(20)]
data = {'Date': dates, 'Value': values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
ts = pd.Series(df['Value'], index=df['Date'])
print(ts)
```

However, print output looks like this:

```
Date
2016-01-01   NaN
2016-01-02   NaN
2016-01-03   NaN
2016-01-04   NaN
2016-01-05   NaN
2016-01-06   NaN
2016-01-07   NaN
2016-01-08   NaN
2016-01-09   NaN
2016-01-10   NaN
2016-01-11   NaN
2016-01-12   NaN
2016-01-13   NaN
2016-01-14   NaN
2016-01-15   NaN
2016-01-16   NaN
2016-01-17   NaN
2016-01-18   NaN
2016-01-19   NaN
2016-01-20   NaN
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Where does `NaN` come from? Is a view on a `DataFrame` object not a valid input for the `Series` class ?

[I have found the `to_series` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html?highlight=to_series#pandas.Index.to_series) for `pd.Index` objects, is there something similar for `DataFrame`s ?

Comment: Are you starting with the dataframe or is it just an intermediate step?

Comment: Starting with a dataframe - which is why I didnt put it in a Series straight away; the data is loaded from a CSV with multiple columns.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you can use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), it convert column `Value` to array:

```
ts = pd.Series(df['Value'].values, index=df['Date'])
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

dates = ['2016-1-{}'.format(i)for i in range(1,21)]
values = [i for i in range(20)]
data = {'Date': dates, 'Value': values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print df['Value'].values
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]

ts = pd.Series(df['Value'].values, index=df['Date'])
```

```
print(ts)
Date
2016-01-01     0
2016-01-02     1
2016-01-03     2
2016-01-04     3
2016-01-05     4
2016-01-06     5
2016-01-07     6
2016-01-08     7
2016-01-09     8
2016-01-10     9
2016-01-11    10
2016-01-12    11
2016-01-13    12
2016-01-14    13
2016-01-15    14
2016-01-16    15
2016-01-17    16
2016-01-18    17
2016-01-19    18
2016-01-20    19
dtype: int64
```

Or you can use:

```
ts1 = pd.Series(data=values, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))
print(ts1)
2016-01-01     0
2016-01-02     1
2016-01-03     2
2016-01-04     3
2016-01-05     4
2016-01-06     5
2016-01-07     6
2016-01-08     7
2016-01-09     8
2016-01-10     9
2016-01-11    10
2016-01-12    11
2016-01-13    12
2016-01-14    13
2016-01-15    14
2016-01-16    15
2016-01-17    16
2016-01-18    17
2016-01-19    18
2016-01-20    19
dtype: int64
```

Thank you [@ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818873/pandas-series-creation-using-dataframe-columns-returns-nan-data-entries/35818917?noredirect=1#comment59305482_35818917) for better explanation why you get `NaN`:

When you give a `Series` or `DataFrame` column to `pd.Series`, it will reindex it using the `index` you specify. Since your `DataFrame` column has an integer `index` (not a `date index`) you get lots of missing values.

Comment: And so I can! Cheers, mate!

Comment: Out of curiousity, from what does it convert the data to list ? I always thought I can think of the returned values of `df['Date']` as an iterable, comparable to lists - is that not the case?

Comment: @j4ck: When you give a Series or DataFrame column to `pd.Series`, it will *reindex* it using the index you specify. Since your DataFrame column has an integer index (not a date index). you get lots of missing values.

Comment: @ajcr - Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
s = df.set_index('Date')
```

Which is now a one column dataframe.

If you really want it as a Series:

```
s = df.set_index('Date').Value
```

btw, NaN is numpy's Not-a-Number.

Using your method, you could use:

```
ts = pd.Series(df['Value'].values, name='Value', index=df['Date'])
```

The reason you are getting the NaNs is that you are not providing the data in the correct format.  You are passing a Series to a Series.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for a to create series with those values you could have also done:

```
 pd.Series( [i for i in range(20)],  pd.date_range('2016-01-02', periods=20, freq='D'))
```