# DataFrame Pandas shows NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have hdf5 and I have moved to DataFrame, but problem is when I want to plot, nothing shows on the graph. And I have checked new dataframe, but I saw, there was nothing.
This is my DF (
[I don't allowed to post pics, so please click to the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgpyg.png) )

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Price, index = df.Timestamp)
plt.figure()
df1.plot()
plt.show()
```

Second DF shows NAN in price column. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `Timestamp`, select column `Price` and plot:

```
#convert column to floats
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)
df.set_index('Timestamp')['Price'].plot()
```

---

```
#if some non numeric data, convert them to NaNs
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
df.set_index('Timestamp')['Price'].plot()
```

And get `NaNs` if use `DataFrame` constructor, because data not aligned - values of index of `df` are not same as `Timestamp` column.

Comment: I think it makes change to first DataFrame. I don't need changes on first dataframe. But don't delete this code, it can be helpfull to others

Comment: If no assign output there is no change.

Comment: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
I receive this kind of error

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding .values, And how about creating a series instead?

```
#df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Price.values, df.Timestamp)
serie = pd.Series(df.Price.values, df.Timestamp)
```

Saw it was answered here: [pandas.Series() Creation using DataFrame Columns returns NaN Data entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818873/pandas-series-creation-using-dataframe-columns-returns-nan-data-entries)

**Full example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Price","Timestamp","Random"])
df.Price = np.random.randint(100, size = 10)
df.Timestamp = [datetime.datetime(2000,1,1) + \
            datetime.timedelta(days=int(i)) for i in np.random.randint(100, size = 10)]
df.Random = np.random.randint(10, size= 10)

serie = pd.Series(df.Price.values, df.Timestamp)

serie.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Difference

```
print("{}\n{}".format(type(df.Price), type(df.Price.values)))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> # does not work
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> # works
```